# Is there an unresolvable circular reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I start my application using springboot, an exception occurs. I have no idea about it.

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="master.datasource")
public DataSource master() {
  return new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "slave1.datasource")
public DataSource slave1() {
  return new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
}

@Bean
public DynamicDataSource dataSource() {
  DynamicDataSource dataSource = new DynamicDataSource();
  dataSource.setMaster(master());
  List<DataSource> slaves = new ArrayList<DataSource>();
  slaves.add(slave1());
  dataSource.setSlaves(slaves);
  return dataSource;
}
```

Here is DynamicDataSource class structure

```
public class DynamicDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    private DataSource master;
    private List<DataSource> slaves;
```

Caused by:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:347)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:220)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:356)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.init(DataSourceInitializer.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
```

Comment: Take more time to format your question - it should be obvious to you that this is not legible. If you cannot be bothered to put 5 minutes of your time into using the formatting tools; I certainly cannot be bothered to put 5 minutes of my time deciphering this atrocity. There's an `enter code here` in the middle of your code for heaven's sake!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to switch off Spring Boot's autoconfiguration of DataSources. Add the following to your main `@Configuration` class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: In this case, do you care to accept my answer as the correct one as well?